# How to add file to Github repo by URL

Tags: github, github-api

My goal is to collect image database from the different websites.
I'm going to create a Chrome plugin to add files just from web pages to my repository.

Is Github supporting the adding file directly from image source URL?
Maybe there are some examples?

Comment: There are likely better places to store images IMO. You  will need an API key to authenticate. Is the chrome plugin for personal use?

Comment: I want to make the generic plugin, to let anyone configure his repo and keys... So, the problem is I cannot find API method to do it directly from URL, I don't want to save files on drive.